# Что может удалять файлы php-сессий на сервере?

Tags: php, modx, сессия, ispmanager

на сервере стоит ISPmanager Lite, на нем крутится один сайт на modx, в настройках modx указано использовать стандартный механизм обработки сессий php.

Проблема: файлы сессий хранятся не более суток, потом удаляются, хотя в php.ini [image: phpinfo] прописано хранить сессии 1 месяц, почему так происходит?

Comment: наверное директории где они хранятся `tmp` временная тобишь

Comment: А нигде параметры сессий не меняются "на лету"? Поищите `ini_set()` с ключами `session.*`

Comment: Загляните в /core/model/modx/modx.class.php. А потом в параметр `session_gc_maxlifetime` в настройках (System Settings)